Google Cloud Platform - Cloud Speech-to-Text V2
I use API, Cloud Speech-to-Text V2 from Google Cloud Platform. I set the environment using JSON file. I want to transcribe an audio file from local to text. When I execute the code, it doesn't show error but shows a lot of encodes. How to revise it?
import os
import asyncio
from google.cloud.speech_v2 import SpeechClient
from google.cloud.speech_v2.types import cloud_speech as speech
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict

# My credential file.
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '../config/google_credential.json'

async def transcribe_audio(local_file_path):
    
    client = SpeechClient()

    with open(local_file_path, "rb") as audio_file:
        content = audio_file.read()
    
    # recognize how many speakers
    diarization_config = speech.SpeakerDiarizationConfig(
        min_speaker_count=2,
        max_speaker_count=6
    )
    features = speech.RecognitionFeatures(
        diarization_config=diarization_config
    )
    
    # Recognition set.
    config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        auto_decoding_config=speech.AutoDetectDecodingConfig(),
        features=features,
        language_codes=["en-US"],
        model="long",
    )
    request = speech.RecognizeRequest(
        config=config,
        content=content
    )
    operation = await client.batch_recognize(request=request)
    response = await operation.result()

    # File result.
    for result in response.results:
        for alternative in result.alternatives:
            print(f"Transcript: {alternative.transcript}")
            print(f"Confidence: {alternative.confidence}")
            for word in alternative.words:
                print(f"Word: {word.word}, Speaker: {word.speaker_tag}")

    response_dict = MessageToDict(response)

    with open("transcript.txt", "w") as transcript_file:
        for result in response_dict['results']:
            for alternative in result['alternatives']:
                transcript_file.write(f"Transcript: {alternative['transcript']}\n")
                transcript_file.write(f"Confidence: {alternative['confidence']}\n")
                for word in alternative['words']:
                    transcript_file.write(f"Word: {word['word']}, Speaker: {word['speakerTag']}\n")

# My file.
local_file_path = "../voice/Chicago.mp3"
asyncio.run(transcribe_audio(local_file_path))

Below is the result I got. However, I want texts from the song not these.
06\377\377\375\234p\213 W\206\020\001h-a9\'&\257\377\377\373\325\212\350\200a\200/\303`\274\324\306\n\251&\026\nXwN\221[vW`\000\t\2723\365:SB\021J\001o\013X\315A\204\233a+\312e\001m\205\336\247v\237xp\245\332G\226\033\236_n\354m\340\213<\2627in2D\357\204\324\226\275M\311\246[|fet\222\372\361\'\371\232o9+\302\320\253F\351\255Kr\275\205\035\266\261bb<\365\221I6\021\030\nf\214\236\205+\265~\213\002\310(\254D2\214\371XUl&\225\246J\357iU\247\351U3\306(\024\201z\275\365\236\335&d9\263\352\350\205\302\337\034\262\344\035\214\027\214\025w\026\212\010/\377\251A`\027\301\014@\200\3311#\377\377\374\367\022\204\tA\263\010\000\246\026\2004N@\000\002\267\255\266\001\0162\300r\005\212\226\210\332$t\026\022O\002\250\033xc\014\016\207\001\003\177#\202^\3314\353

